# c - grouping strings in a struct

Tags: c, string, struct

I have a bunch of strings that look like:

`'Hello1-FOO', 'Aello2-FOO', 'Bye1-BAR', 'Bye3-BAR', 'Hello22-FOO', 'Bye4-BAR', 'Welcome-BAR' ...`

All of them are stored on a struct.

```
struct str {
    char *strings;
}
...
struct str **t_str;
size_t j;
t_str = malloc(sizeof *t_str * 20);
for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    t_str[j] = malloc(sizeof *t_str[j]);
...
t_str[0]->strings = "Hello1-FOO";
t_str[1]->strings = "Aello2-FOO";
....
```

What I would like to do is to display (sort) them by category, so they look similar to this:

```
FOO:
 Hello1-FOO
 Aello2-FOO
 Hello22-FOO

BAR:
 Bye4-BAR
 Welcome-BAR
 Bye1-BAR
 Bye3-BAR
```

Basically group them by the token after the '-'

What would be a good way of doing this? Should I store them on a second struct after processing the string? Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The first thing to fix is that your struct allows for only one string.  If that's the real code, you haven't gotten far enough to have this problem yet.

Comment: @David Thornley: I have already allocated memory for all the strings mentioned above. I can display them (ungrouped) without problem. I just wanted to comment where they being held.

Comment: So do you have one `str` instance for each string? That's what your code looks like, but the description made it sound like you wanted to store all the strings in a single `str` instance

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Sorry for the wrong description. Yes I have one str instance for each string.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/). The following code makes some assumptions but you should be able to change it to suit your needs.

```
int categoryComparitor(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  char *string1 = (char *)a;
  char *string2 = (char *)b;

  string1 = strrchr(string1, '-') + 1;
  string2 = strrchr(string2, '-') + 1;

  return strcmp(string1, string2);
}


{
  ...
  char *strings[];  // Array of string pointers
  int stringCount;  // Holds current number of valid elements in strings.
  ...
  qsort(strings, stringCount, sizeof(char *), categoryComparitor);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using standard libary functions instead of reinventing.

Answer (score 0):

As David Thornley already pointed out, your `struct` isn't really defined well to handle this situation (well at all). Since your input is two separate logical pieces, you really want to define the struct accordingly -- containing two separate strings, one for each part of the input.

```
struct record { 
    char *category;
    char *string;
};
```

Then you want to read each piece into one of those two strings:

```
record read_line(FILE *infile) { 
    char buffer1[128], buffer2[128];
    fscanf(infile, "%[^-]-%s", buffer1, buffer2);
    record ret;
    ret.string = dupe_string(buffer1);
    ret.category = dupe_string(buffer2);
    return ret;
}
```

Then, to sort those records, you'll want to define a comparison function with the signature expected by `qsort`, that does a comparison on the `category` member:

```
int cmp(void *a, void *b) { 
    return strcmp(((record *)a)->category, ((record *)b)->category);
}
```

Then you'll sort your array of `record`s using that comparison function.